# CMake in VS 2017 don't show build log while build

Tags: c++, build, cmake, visual-studio-2017

When I build any CMake target in my CMake project ( open as "open folder" ) from VS 2017 IDE I didn't see any output, so can't understand what happened for example in case builder or linker errors...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is resolve by set option:

"**Tools**" > "**Options**"
"**Projects and Solutions**" > "**General**"
Check the option "**Show Output window when build starts**"

The next time you build, the "Build" option in the "Output" windows will appear and be automatically selected.